# php mail() permission denied /var/spool/exim and /var/log/exim

Tags: php, httpd, centos7, exim

Clean install of CentOS 7, Exim 4.84, Httpd 2.4.6, php 5.4.16

Sending mails through exim works.
Sending mails in the console with sendmail-command works.
Sending mails with mail() in php gives these error messages (in /var/log/maillog):

```
Aug  2 15:03:04 v024 exim[1311]: 2016-08-02 15:03:04 1bUZLc-0000L9-D3 Failed to create spool file /var/spool/exim/input//1bUZLc-0000L9-D3-D: Permission denied
Aug  2 15:03:04 v024 exim[1311]: 2016-08-02 15:03:04 1bUZLc-0000L9-D3 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim/main.log": Permission denied: euid=93 egid=93
Aug  2 15:03:04 v024 exim[1311]: exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above
```

Checked file permissions, everything looks good:

```
drwxr-x---. 2 exim exim     4096 Aug  2 14:32 /var/log/exim
-rw-r-----. 1 exim exim 19351762 Aug  2 15:11 /var/log/exim/main.log
-rw-r-----. 1 exim exim     1010 Aug  2 08:46 /var/log/exim/reject.log

drwxr-x---. 6 exim exim       75 Jul 19 13:25 /var/spool/exim
drwxr-x---. 2 exim exim       94 Jul 13 21:01 /var/spool/exim/db
-rw-r-----. 1 exim exim      382 Jul 19 13:25 /var/spool/exim/exim-process.info
drwxr-x---. 2 exim exim    36864 Aug  2 15:11 /var/spool/exim/input
drwxr-x---. 2 exim exim    20480 Aug  2 15:11 /var/spool/exim/msglog
drwxr-x---. 2 exim exim        6 Aug  2 13:01 /var/spool/exim/scan
```

Comment: Who is `euid=93 egid=93`?

Comment: user/group 93 is exim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is often a [SELinux problem](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting.html), you need to [set the correct boolean](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Booleans.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Booleans-Configuring_Booleans):

```
 setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```